# MS Access count query does not produce wanted results

Tags: ms-access

I have a table (tblExam) showing exam data score designed as follow:

Exam Name:  String
Score: number(pecent)

Basically I am trying to pull the records by Exam name where the score are less than a specific amount (0.695 in my case).

I am using the following statement to get the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tblExam.name, Count(tblExam.name) AS CountOfName
FROM tblExam WHERE (((tblExam.Score)<0.695))
GROUP BY tblExam.name;
```

This works fine but does not display the exam that have 0 records more than 0.695; in other words I am getting this:

```
Exam Name     count    
firstExam       2  
secondExam      1  
thirdExam       3
```

The count of 0 and any exams with score above 0.695 do not show up.  What I would like is something like this:

```
Exam Name     count  
firstExam       2  
secondExam      1  
thirdExam       3  
fourthExam      0  
fifthExam       0  
sixthExam       2  
.  
..  
.etc...
```

I hope that I am making sense here.  I think that I need somekind of LEFT JOIN to display all of the exam name but I can not come up with the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to display all *name* groups and, within each group, the count of `Score < 0.695`.  So I think you should move `< 0.695` from the `WHERE` to the `Count()` expression --- actually remove the `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT
    e.name,
    Count(IIf(e.Score < 0.695, 1, Null)) AS CountOfName
FROM tblExam AS e
GROUP BY e.name;
```

That works because `Count()` counts only non-Null values.  You could use `Sum()` instead of `Count()` if that seems clearer:

```sql
    Sum(IIf(e.Score < 0.695, 1, 0)) AS CountOfName
```

Note `DISTINCTROW` is not useful in a `GROUP BY` query, because the grouping makes the rows unique without it.  So I removed `DISTINCTROW` from the query.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly for my need and a lot better and simpler than the solution that I eventually found:SELECT DISTINCTROW e.name, NZ(ee.NumOfFailure,0) AS NumberOfFailures
FROM tblExam AS e LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCTROW name, Count(name) AS NumOfFailure FROM tblExam WHERE (((Score)<0.695)) GROUP BY tblExam.PO, tblExam.ExamNo)  AS ee ON e.name = ee.name
GROUP BY e.name, ee.NumOfFailure;      Sorry but I can not vote you up because apparently I do not have enough reputation points (15).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Do I detect a contradiction? The query calls for results <0.695 but your text says you are also looking for results >0.695. Perhaps I don't understand. Does this give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tblExam.ExamName, Count(tblExam.ExamName) AS CountOfExamName
FROM tblExam
WHERE (((tblExam.Score)<0.695 Or (tblExam.Score)>0.695))
GROUP BY tblExam.ExamName;
```